# Many-To-Many Surrogate Key problem. Please help!

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I have a [many-to-many relationship](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/usersguide/relations/hasandbelongs.html) with surrogate key

The classes are: Insurer - InsurerSection - Section.

InsurerSection has one extra attribute: active : bool.

How do I access these bool property? Is it possible to have this property contained within the Insurer and Section objects or do I have to call something like:

```
InsurerSection.FindOne(Expression.Eq("Section", sectionObj)).Active;
```

The best would be to have a reference in Insurer and Section like:

```
Insurer item = new Insurer();
item.Active = true;
```

OR

```
Section item = new Section();
item.Active = true;
```

Is that possible? What options do I have?

Thanks!
Jakub

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

```
Insurer item = new Insurer();
item.Active = true;
```

which `InsurerSection` should be marked with active = true ?

Either use `FindOne` as you suggested or [map the relationship as a map/dictionary](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-ofvalues) (unfortunately ActiveRecord doesn't support `index-many-to-many` yet)